# overuse of __syncthread in the code

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I understand the purpose of `__syncthreads()`, but I sometimes find it overused in some codes.

For instance, in the code below taken from NVIDIA notes, each thread calculates mainly `s_data[tx]-s_data[tx-1]`. Each thread needs the data it reads from the global memory and the data read by its neighboring thread. Both threads will be in the same warp and hence should complete retrieval of their data from the global memory and are scheduled for execution simultaneously.

I believe the code will still work without `__syncthread()`, but obviously the NVIDIA notes say otherwise. Any comment, please?

```
// Example – shared variables
// optimized version of adjacent difference
__global__ void adj_diff(int *result, int *input)
{
    // shorthand for threadIdx.x
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    // allocate a __shared__ array, one element per thread
    __shared__ int s_data[BLOCK_SIZE];
    // each thread reads one element to s_data
    unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + tx;
    s_data[tx] = input[i];
    // avoid race condition: ensure all loads
    // complete before continuing
    __syncthreads();

    if(tx > 0)
        result[i] = s_data[tx] – s_data[tx–1];
    else if(i > 0)
    {
        // handle thread block boundary
        result[i] = s_data[tx] – input[i-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: There are only two cases where you don't need __syncthreads(): if the code is truly warp-synchronous (which as Robert has pointed out in the answer, it is not; and in any case you'd have to mark the pointers as volatile in order for warp synchronous code to work), or if each thread is reading a shared memory location that it, itself, wrote.  Threads always have a self-consistent view of memory.

Comment: Is there any reference where i have to read more about your statement "and in any case you'd have to mark the pointers as volatile in order for warp synchronous code to work", any reference/example please

Comment: It's in the NVIDIA documentation, if you look for it. http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0_rc2/sdk/docs/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notes.txt

Also discussed in my book (The CUDA Handbook).

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice if you included a link to where, in the "Nvidia notes", this appeared.

> both threads will be in the same warp

No, they won't, at least not in all cases.   What happens when `tx` = 32?  Then the thread corresponding to `tx` belongs to warp 1 in the block, and the thread corresponding to `tx-1` belongs to warp 0 in the block.

There's no guarantee that warp 0 has executed before warp 1, so the code could fail without the call to `__synchtreads()` (since, without  it, the value of `s_data[tx-1]` could be invalid, since warp 0 hasn't run and therefore hasn't loaded it yet.)

Comment: thanks for your answer and it is my mistake...thought result[i]=s_data[x]-input[i-1] handle all the boundary cases